# How to automatically update virtual model property when updating its foreign key reference?

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have a `order` table that refers to `status` table by foreign key `status_id`:

```
$ select order_id, status_id from "order";

 order_id | status_id 
----------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

The `Order` model in Sequelize also includes (virtual?) `.status` property for convenience:

> I'm using NestJS and `sequlize-typescript`.

```
class Order extends Model {
  @Column({
    field: 'order_id',
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  readonly id!: string;

  readonly statusID!: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Status, {
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'statusID',
      field: 'status_id',
    },
  })
  readonly status!: Status;
}
```

```
class Status extends Model { … }
```

To progress a given order to another status, I want to use `.update()` method of a model. To do that, I have to set both `status` and `statusID`:

```
const order = await Order.finByPk(…);
const newStatus = await Status.findOne(…);

await order.update({
  status: newStatus,
  statusID: newStatus.id,
});
```

This is logic duplication, it is error-prone, I don't want to do that. But:

- if I set only `status`, the `statusID` is not updated on the `order` instance, and the foreign key reference is not updated in the table, rendering the whole change as moot;
- if I set only `statusID`, the table is properly updated, but `order.status` still points to the old status, requiring another read from the table (`Order.findByPk(…)`);

In both cases, the `order` instance becomes inconsistent: `order.statusID` and `order.status.id` have different values.

**Is it possible to set only `statusID` in `.update(…)`, and force Sequelize to automatically update `order.status`?**

Answer (score 0):

*(Partial answer)*

An alternative to using `Model.findByPk(…)` (which both performs a read and creates a new instance of `Model`) would be using `model.reload()`, which preserves model instance while making the read.

So, instead of:

```
await order.update({ statusID: newStatus.id });

const orderUpdated = await Order.findByPk(order.id);

return orderUpdated;
```

… it is:

```
await order.update({ statusID: newStatus.id });
await order.reload({ include: ['status'] });

return order;
```

This is more concise and definitely better, however, not the best, since the issue of requiring another read from the table still persists.

Answer (score 0):

To fix logic duplication, one can define a model instance method and encapsulate the logic there:

```
class Order extends Model {
  readonly statusID!: string;
  readonly status!: Status;

  async setStatus(newValue: Status): Promise<void> {
    await this.update({
      statusID: newValue.id,
      status: newValue,
    });
  }
}
```

… which can then be generalized in order to be useful for other models:

```
import type { Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import type { Attributes } from 'sequelize/types';

const createForeignModelSetter = <
  OriginalModel extends Model = Model,
  ForeignModel extends Model = Model,
>(
  foreignKey: keyof Attributes<OriginalModel>,
  foreignModelKey: keyof Attributes<OriginalModel>,
  foreignModelPrimaryKey: keyof Attributes<ForeignModel>,
) =>
  async function (this: OriginalModel, newValue: ForeignModel): Promise<void> {
    await this.update({
      [foreignKey]: newValue[foreignModelPrimaryKey],
      [foreignModelKey]: newValue,
    });
  };
```

```
class Status extends Model<{ id: string }> { … }
```

```
class Order extends Model<{ statusID: string, status: Status }> {
  readonly setStatus = createForeignModelSetter<Order, Status>(
    'statusID',
    'status',
    'id',
  );
}
```

This significantly improves the logic duplication situation, but not fixes completely (hiding is not fixing).